# Auth0: Single Log out for .NET 6 based apps using C#

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, auth0

We are using Auth0 as Identity provider. We are working towards Single Logout functionality. We are taking help from Auth0 support and its taking some time. Feels like we are the 1st Auth0 customer who is looking for SLO for .NET 6 based apps.

We have some limitation also. We don't want to use Auth0 JS library to and we can't use back channel logout functionality.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

best regards
S

Comment: you could follow these steps to implement your requiremnet:1)Configure federated logout in Auth0 to log the user out and redirect them back to your app, where you'll then clear the local session2)manage app sessions correctly, terminate the local session when the user logs out3)Implement a browser-based logout for SLO across multiple applications, potentially using iframes to trigger logouts on each application's logout endpoint4)Regularly check with Auth0 to confirm if the session is still active and handle accordingly

Comment: Please refer my point wise reply. 1) Configure Federated Logout? This is totally new to me at this point in time. Clearing local session is not an issue. Session with Auth0 is not clearing up for SLO 2) We are killing the Application session properly when user is logging out 3) Could you please add more to this point as this is not clears to me. 4) This can be only done using JS library for Auth0 which we dont want to use. We have not seen any method in SDK (NET6).  Thanks alot for your respone. If you can add more pointers to point no3, the same would be very helpful.

Comment: here is the detailed description of the 3rd point: when user logout you cab clear the session and redirect user to the  Auth0 logout URL with parameter which says the session is clear. eg.https://DOMAIN/v2/logout?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&returnTo=YOUR_RETURN_TO_URL. Redirect the user to Auth0's logout URL to ensure the Auth0 session is cleared. Include the `returnTo` URL parameter that points to where the user should be redirected after the logout. If the user is logged into other applications in the same SSO session, those applications also need to be notified.

Comment: You mentioned "Implement a browser-based logout for SLO across multiple applications, potentially using iframes to trigger logouts on each application's logout endpoint" Could you please elaborate more on this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for us :-

Hit the session end point "https://dev.mcc.auth0app.com/oauth/token" from management API from Auth0 and check for 404 status. If status is 404, it means time to logout the user ( user logged out from a different site).

In our app(1st tab in browser), we have a link to another app. When user clicks that link, another app opens(2nd tab). And we logout from the 2nd tab. Once we are back to main app (1st tab) and access any functionality, user should be re-directed to login screen. And this is working now. Some more fine tunning is required.

Actual implemenation is as follows:-

The following method was add in base controller :-

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
...
...
...

    if (context.HttpContext.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated &&
        context.HttpContext.Session.Get("sid") != null)
    {
        
        Task<AccessTokenResponse> tokenTask =  Auth0MgmtApiUtil.GetAccessToken(_auth0Settings, 
            Logger);
    
        if(tokenTask != null)
        {
            tokenResp = tokenTask.Result;
            string tokenType = tokenResp.token_type;
            string token = tokenResp.access_token;
            string sessionId = GetSIDFromClaims("sid");
            Task<string> apiTask = Auth0MgmtApiUtil.GetAuthSession(_auth0Settings.SessionEndpoint, 
                tokenResp, 
                sessionId,
                Logger);
            if (apiTask != null)
            {
                string data = apiTask.Result;
                var sessionMissing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SSOSessionMissingResponse>(data);
                if (sessionMissing != null)
                {
                    // Session was killed
                    // {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Session not found for ID c7TXfxVkFy5I50z7WdW2pvH6XjoHSEcU10R6w4"}
                    if (sessionMissing.statusCode?.ToString() == "404")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

This is working for us. In our application, we are hitting controllers using javascript.

FYI - "sid" is from Auth0 which we get from claims.

best regrads